# chmod: How to recursively add execute permissions only to files which already have execute permission

Tags: linux, unix, shell, chmod

I noticed:

`chmod -R a+x` adds execute permissions to all files, not just those who are currently executable.

Is there a way to add execute permissions only to those files who already have an execute set for the user permission?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find . -perm /u+x -execdir chmod a+x {} \;
```

Comment: Use `-execdir`; it's safer than `-exec`.  Also since `chmod` accepts multiple files in one command line, `+` instead of `\;` may have better performance.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the `+` mode! The `-execdir` instead of `-exec` squashes the gained performance benefit again, though; and since find delivers full file paths anyway, does it matter much? the fastest command for me was `... -exec chmod <mode> {} +`

Answer (score 5):

You can use find to get all those files:

```
find . -type f -perm -o+rx -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+x
```

**Update**: add -print0 to preserve space in filenames

Comment: Don't do it that way, it screws up with spaces in the filenames. If you want to pipe to xargs, use the `-print0` find option and the `-0` xargs option.